# Why does my tailwind height transition not apply to an image element?

Tags: tailwind-css

I'm trying to implement a transition on an image so when I hover over it, the image expands with a smooth transition. I've recreated my issue on Tailwind Play https://play.tailwindcss.com/QfZSly1nEB.

As shown, hovering over the image works as expected and the image size changes, however it is not animated as is expected. I've followed the guidance in the [docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/transition-property) regarding transition properties but with no luck

Answer (score 1):

it is because of the class h-auto. if you change it to an absolute value, the transition will works.

https://play.tailwindcss.com/C68QXPaQs0

Comment: Ahh, that would explain it. Is there any way I can enable it so that it works with `h-auto`. Having an absolute value wouldn't really work in my use case due to the image size being dynamic

Comment: @hcphoon you have to customize your scale. see the answear from CorySheppard, Customizie in the taiklwindCSS config file.

Answer (score 0):

Maik's answer works perfectly, but you also have the option of using scale on hover if you want it to centrally stay in the same place.

https://play.tailwindcss.com/JISPGXFeIT